# Maven multiple local repositories for containerized CI

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, maven-repository

Our Java applications have many dependencies, and during CI a lot of time is spent on downloading the artifacts. Since many dependencies are used in almost all applications (Hadoop, Scala, Jackson, etc., various versions), they are downloaded again and again on each application CI. The CI process is containerized for obvious reasons, and the entire .m2 folder is disposed with the container when done.

An idea came up to have 2 local repositories:

1. Read only repository, **on a shared mount**, containing all the shared dependencies
2. Writable, disposable repository **on the CI container** for downloading exclusive artifacts

But I couldn't find any way to configure Maven in such a way. Is it possible at all?

---

EDIT: the question is about LOCAL repository, where all the artifacts are being downloaded into, for the build itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Put the ".m2" directory as not disposible... in your CI ... and reuse it? What kind of CI solution do you use?

Comment: Use a Maven repository that is not a local filesystem repository like Nexus or Artifactory.

Comment: @khmarbaise, aled, maybe the question was not clear, please see the edit

Comment: I exactly meant that...

Comment: What is also possible for example do some caching as other container based CI systems offer ... (but that cost the price of unpackaging the cached things)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is: You shouldn't dispose the local repository after the build.

You should have the local repository in a volume that is mounted into the container.

Comment: We have hundreds of different applications with different dependencies and versions, do you suggest that we keep all dependencies on disk? Also, to my best knowledge, Maven does not excel in concurrent downloads from different builds (correct?). Would this not be a problem?

Comment: The standard practice is to keep one local repository for each project on disk. Of course, this can be some hundreds of GB, and may have to delete it from time to time with a cron job. And yes, this is not really efficient to have some hundred local repositories which coincide in a lot of their content. You could try to construct something like a shared cache from which you copy the content at the start of the container but I haven't seen that in practice yet.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. That makes sense, and I'm pretty sure it also fits in our infra. Kindly consider adding this elaboration to the answer.